# nth-child selector for targeting 1st and 4th, and 2nd and 3rd elements repeatedly

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to do a css selector with nth-child to create something similar with this, but i think its not possible.

The main problem is repeating this.

[image]

```
  a:nth-child(3n+1) {
    grid-column: 1/4;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }

  a:nth-child(3n+2) {
    grid-column: 4/13;
    border: 1px solid blue;
  }
<div class="box-container">
 <a href="#">1</a>
 <a hred="#">2</a>
<a href="#">3</a>
 <a hred="#">4</a>
 <a href="#">1</a>
 <a hred="#">2</a>
<a href="#">3</a>
 <a hred="#">4</a>
</div>
```

**Update:**
And what about this?? Maybe better to use grid-area-template? or the nth-child? or not possible at all? Image below[image]

Comment: Why are you starting with `3n`, when the “grouping” of elements you want is actually _four_ each …? You want something like `a:nth-child(4n), a:nth-child(4n+1)` or similar.

Comment: yeah, i found that out :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:nth-child` as

```css
.item:nth-child(4n) {
  grid-column: 10/13;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.item:nth-child(4n+1) {
  grid-column: 1/4;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.item:nth-child(4n+2) {
  grid-column: 4/13;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.item:nth-child(4n+3) {
  grid-column: 1/10;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.item {
  height: 100px;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: and if i want something more complex than two lines? i've updated the example above.

Comment: @dutraveller Then I will suggest you to wrap the items into different different grid container row-wise according to your requirment because as there is no repeating pattern in your complex structure

Answer (score 1):

```
  a:nth-child(4n+1) {
    grid-column: 1/5;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }

  a:nth-child(4n+2) {
    grid-column: 5/13;
    border: 1px solid blue;
  }

  a:nth-child(4n+3) {
    grid-column: 1/9;
    border: 1px solid green;
  }

  a:nth-child(4n+4) {
    grid-column: 9/13;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
  }
```